# Flutter display logo over camera preview and capture

Tags: flutter, dart, camera

I'm trying to show the logo over the camera preview. If the user click the capture button logo should be placed in the image. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try using ``Stack``. Under stack keep your widgets as : [ yourcamera_widget(), Image() ]

Comment: OMi Shah, Thanks for your response. I have tried that but the camera image only saved.